# Execute launchctl in sandboxed mac app

Tags: macos, sandbox, launchd

I need to execute the `launchctl load/unload` command from my sandboxed OSX app. The app has `read-write` permissions to the folder where the launch agent's `plist` file resides (using security scoped bookmarks which the user of the app is granting before).

However the app gets the following error:

```
-
5/22/13 9:15:56.420 AM sandboxd[28463]: ([28473]) launchctl(28473) deny file-read-data /private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.501/overrides.plist
-
```

To make it clear, I do not want to add my own app to the launch items for autostart and I also found this http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg80413.html conversation on a similar topic without any results yet.

Answer (score 3):

The file `/private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.501/overrides.plist` cand only be read or write by the administrator user (root). So for `launchctl load\unload` to work you must be root, or use `sudo`, to elevate, before the command. But, in sandbox you are not allowed to do this.

Depending on your needs you can use an Helper app. Take a look at [Adding Login Items Using the Service Management Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html).

Answer (score 1):

In order for an application to do something that requires a privileged operation, Apple suggests that a helper app is created, which can only be called to run by the parent application, due to being signed. The helper app is launched with elevated permissions and performs the minimum required actions. Take a look at SMJobBless here: -

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html

As it states: -

> SMJobBless demonstrates how to securely install a helper tool that
>   performs a privileged operation and how to associate the tool with an
>   application that invokes it.

Comment: Thank you, but the `SMJobBless` example also uses a method call of the "Authorization Services" (`AuthorizationCopyRights`) and Apple docs state: "Important: The authorization services API is not supported within an app sandbox because it allows privilege escalation."

Comment: That's a good point that I overlooked. I was going to tell you to take a look at the "EvenBetterAuthorizationSample" from Apple, but it too uses the Authorization Services. I'm starting to think what you're asking isn't possible as the sandbox is too restrictive.

Comment: Yeah, just to be clear for anyone seeing this answer, it's worth noting sandboxed apps are not allowed to elevate privileges, and though sandboxed apps can include helper apps, the helper apps must be sandboxed as well.